# How to select the data from the many-to-many relationship table that matches the desired value?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-query-builder

I'm still new to Laravel. I want to select the **mainchallengecategories** with field role_id on the table that holds the relationship that is equal to 3 because I want only the user who has role_id = 3 to see the **mainchallengecategories**. What should I do with my controller?

I have 4 tables

**1. mainchallengecategories**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Category A |
| 2 | Category B |
| 3 | Category C |
| 4 | Category D |

**2. users**

| id | name | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UserA | 1 |
| 2 | UserB | 2 |
| 3 | UserC | 3 |
| 4 | UserD | 3 |

**3. roles**

| id | name | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin | 1 |
| 2 | staff | 2 |
| 3 | user | 3 |

**4. main_challenge_categories_role**

| id | main_challenge_categories_id | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |

**Here is MainChallengeCategories Model**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}

public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
}

public function main_challenge_categories_role(){
    return $this->hasMany(MainChallengeCategoryRole::class);
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role');
}
```

**Role Model**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

**MainChallengeCategoryRole Model**

```
protected $fillable=['main_challenge_categories_id', 'role_id'];

public function mainchallengecategories(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MainChallengeCategories','main_challenge_categories_id');
}
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','role_id');
}
```

**MainChallengeCategoryController**

```
public function create(){
```

**/*$mainchallengecategories = MainChallengeCategoryRole::with('mainchallengecategories') // Eager loading
->where('role_id', '3')
->get();*/**

**What should I do here in this function????????**

```
    return view('user.addChallenge')
    ->with('mainchallengecategories',$mainchallengecategories);
}
```

**Thank you for everyone's kindness here that I have always received in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

in `Role.php`:

```
public function mainChallengeCategoryRoles(){
  return $this->hasMany(MainChallengeCategoryRole::class, 'role_id', 'id');
}
```

Get Main challenge category roles of the Role:

```
$mainchallengecategories = Role::find(3)->mainChallengeCategoryRoles;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to put  public function mainChallengeCategoryRoles(){
  return $this->hasMany(MainChallengeCategoryRole::class, 'role_id', 'id');
} in Role.php and put the $mainchallengecategories = Role::find(3)->mainChallengeCategoryRoles; in my MainChallengeCategoryController.

I got a list of mainchallengecategories as empty in the options of drop-down listing but no errors.